# Replace Tilde with $HOME in bash script

Tags: string, bash, shell, replace

I've been digging through the internet and I see examples of replacing `$HOME` with `~`, but I'm trying to go the other way (e.g. - replace `~` with `$HOME` and currently if I try to run this:

```
if [[ $directory_name = *~* ]]; then
  echo "${$directory_name/\~/$HOME}"
fi
```

to replace it, I get this error:

`${$directory_name/\~/$HOME}: bad substitution`

I have `#!/bin/bash` at the top of my script file and when I run it I've been using something like this:

`sh test-script.sh`

I'm also doing this in terminal on a Mac, so I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Again...new to bash scripting so while this *seems* logical, I could be going about this all wrong and missing something. Thanks!

Comment: `echo "${directory_name/\~/$HOME}"`

Comment: You also probably don't want `*~*`. `~` should only be replaced with `$HOME` if it forms the complete first directory component. `~user/` is the home directory of user `user`. Otherwise, `~` is just a character.

Comment: ...there are other special cases -- `~-` has a non-`$HOME` meaning, for example; so does `~+`.

Comment: I know its closed but if someone else comes to this I Want them to see an answer
echo "~" | sed "s/^~/${HOME//\//\\/}/ig"
the ig is not needed just a habit